# The second eigenvalue of a reducible stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, markov-process

The magnitude of the second dominant eigenvalue of a reducible matrix, as I know, is supposed to be 1, why it's not the case for this matrix :

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

This is a reducible matrix, but the eigenvalues I'm having are these :

(-0.50000, 0.50000i)

( 0.00000, 0.00000i)

( 1.00000, 0.00000i)

(-0.50000,-0.50000i)

As you can see the second dominant eigenvalue is not 1, am I missing something ?

Comment: unless I am mistaken, the second eigenvalue $(1.00000,0.00000i)$ is $1$?

Comment: @ellya : I meant second dominant eigenvalue, see updates